# по нажатию одной кнопки нажимались и другие

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Начал изучать html/css. с js и $ почти не знаком) написал несколько форм и добавил на каждой невидимую кнопку submit. как сделать, чтобы по нажатию на button в конце нескольких форм, на каждой из них нажалась кнопка и данные отправились на сервер
логика элементарна, но незнание синтаксиса это проблема)
на всех сабмитах поставил один класс и думал, что по нажатию на финальную кнопку все будет ок, но что-то пошло не так) заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для нажатия существует функция `click`. С помощью неё можно нажать на любой элемент. Так же есть такое событие на фокус и прочее.

Вариант JS:

```js
function allClick() {
  var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button');
  for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].click();
  };
};
```

```html
<button class="button" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 1')">Кнопка 1</button>
<button class="button" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 2')">Кнопка 2</button>
<button class="button" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 3')">Кнопка 3</button>
<p><button onclick="allClick()">Нажать на все</button></p>
```

Вариант JQuery:

```js
function allClick() {
  $('.button').click()
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 1')">Кнопка 1</button>
<button class="button" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 2')">Кнопка 2</button>
<button class="button" onclick="console.log('Кнопка 3')">Кнопка 3</button>
<p><button onclick="allClick()">Нажать на все</button></p>
```

Comment: Yuri, большое спасибо, за помощь)